# JS : Create a json with dynamic keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Let's say i have 2 arrays of possible numerical values :

```
var reg = [1000, 1010, 2050];
var ag = [100, 101, 102];
```

I want to create a object/json of the kind :

```
[ 1000 : [100, 101], 1010 : [100, 101, 102], 2050 : [100, 102]];
```

These values would be retrieved from the checkboxes the user would have checked :

```
<input type="checkbox" data-reg="1000" data-ag="100" class="agcheck" />
<input type="checkbox" data-reg="1000" data-ag="101" class="agcheck" />
...
<input type="checkbox" data-reg="xxx" data-ag="yyy" class="agcheck" />
```

The xxx and yyy would be all the possible values from the array
and

```
var obj = {}; //or var arr = [];
$('.agcheck:checked').each(function(){
    var ag = parseInt($(this).data('ag'));
    var reg = parseInt($(this).data('reg'));
    //what i need here
 }
```

How can i create such an object in javascript ?

In the loop

- I can't do  obj.reg.push(ag) because i would have "Cannot read
  property 'push' of undefined"
- I can't do  obj.push(reg:ag) because i would have an array like `[0:[reg:100], 1:[reg:101]...]` the key (here `reg`) would not be set as such
- I don't want `obj.push({'reg':reg,'ag':ag})` because i want the key being the reg value.

====

Thanks to the answer of #SLaks i managed to get it right :

```
var obj = {}; //or var arr = [];
$('.agcheck:checked').each(function(){
    var ag = parseInt($(this).data('ag'));
    var reg = parseInt($(this).data('reg'));
    if (obj[reg] == undefined) {
        obj[reg] = [];
    }
    obj[reg].push(ag);
 }
```

Comment: what are the rules for adding `[100, 101], 1010 : [100, 101, 102], 2050 : [100, 102]]`

Comment: As i explained in the question : i have checkboxes for all the combinations, i the values i retrieve are those the user check and submits. So, in my example, the checkbox with `data-reg=1000 data-ag=100` would have been checked, but not the checkbox with `data-reg=1000 data-ag=102`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To set a property of an object, use bracket notation:

```
obj[name] = value;
```